# Same sequence interwoven with itself creating groups

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, number-theory, sequence

If we take all the digits from 1 to 9 and lay them out in order.
123456789
Now repeat the sequence and add it to the end.
123456789123456789
Now let's copy and reverse everything to create a second sequence
987654321987654321
Now we merge both together and wrap them into a circle. So we have 18 digits running in order clockwise and 18 digits running in reverse anticlockwise.
[image: circle of an 18 digit sequence running in both directions]

The above image is an example of how the numbers could be arranged
Now if we examine the arrangement we can find a place where we can split the circle into orthogonally connected sections of 9 cells where no digit repeats.
[image: circle split into 4 sections of non repeating digits]

**Question**
Is there are way of arranging the gaps between the clockwise and anticlockwise sequences around the circle in such a way to make it impossible to divide the circle into 4 sections where each section contains all of the digits 1 to 9 without repeats?

Or can you prove that no matter how the 2 sequences interweave around the circle there will always be a place where you can split the circle into 4 groups without repeated digits?
Note
The star in the image is meaningless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> always possible to split.

Proof

> Lets call numbers *up* and *down* depending on which sequence they came from before intermixing. In OP up numbers are red and down numbers green. Pick a pair of neighbouring up and down numbers.

> 1. If their values are equal (k, say) then the ccw one forms a full set with its 8 ccw neighbours (and the cw one with its 8 cw neighbours). Indeed, there will be some number j of up neighbours taking values k+1,k+2,...,k+j (mod 9) and 8-j down neighbours taking values k-1, k-2,...,k-8+j=k+j+1 (mod 9).

> Further, the next 9 neighbours ccw form another full set by essentially the same argument (Split into up and down numbers and observe that  they cover complementary (contiguous) subsets). And so on.

> 2. If their values are different, u and d, say, then again by essentially the same argument u and d together with their d-u-1 (mod 9) ccw neighbours (which take values u+1,u+2,...,d-1 (mod 9)) and their u-d-1 (mod 9) cw neighbours (which take values d+1,d+2,...,u-1 (mod 9)) form a full set. As above the next 9 ccw (or cw) also form a full set.

Comment: Does the split still work if the sequence runs 3 times clockwise and only once anticlockwise

Comment: @Maff not 100% sure but off the top of my head I can't see a reason the proof wouldn't go through unchanged.